# How to prevent the auth0 third party cookies

Tags: javascript, authentication, auth0

I'm using auth0 silent authentication in a react project.

```
  login(email, password) {
    const params = {
      connection: '*****************',
      scope: '**********',
      email: '***********@*****',
      password: '*****************'
    };
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.instance.popup.loginWithCredentials(params, (error, data) => {
        if (error) {
          reject(error);
          return;
        }
        resolve({
          expiresIn: data.expiresIn,
          accessToken: data.accessToken
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

I can't login unless third party cookies are unblocked.

[image]

as I read silent authentication use third party cookies.

so any solution to prevent those cookies and unaffected to our functionalities?

Answer (score 0):

Silent login must maintain state somewhere on the client, but you can get around it by setting up [Custom Domain](https://auth0.com/docs/custom-domains) (requires a payed account). This way the cookie won't be considered as a 3rd party and browser won't block it.

Comment: I enabled the custom domain from auth0 console but still thrid party cookies remains

Comment: Did you check that it actually uses this domain and not *.auth0.com via dev console's network tab?